# Как в Yii2-Start создать контроллер или модуль?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2

Установил Yii2-Start, не могу разобраться где создавать контроллеры, модули и т.д. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Это вопрос к стартовой странице, а не на SO.

Answer (score 2):

Контроллеры нужно создавать в папке `Controllers`, модули в папке `Modules`, если этих папок нет там, где они должны быть, то нужно создать эти папки. Если не знаете где создавать, то ищите папку `web` и создавайте рядом с ней.

Comment: Это я все понимаю. Создал контроллер, но не могу его открыть через браузер. Захожу на http://yii.loc/test/index, Not Found.

Comment: @vettelseb, а вьюху вы создали в папке `views`?